# Cleaner way of doing SQL statement with IN clause

Tags: go

I'm trying to do a MySQL update with a `IN` clause, which I've managed to get working with the following

```
    // These values are read from the DB earlier.
    pks := []uint64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    status := "SUCCESS"

    sql := fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE event SET event_status = ? WHERE event_pk IN (?%s)", status, strings.Repeat(",?", len(pks)-1))

    var params []interface{}
    for _, pk := range pks {
        params = append(params, pk)
    }

    rows, err := db.Update(sql, params...)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }

    return rows.RowsAffected()
```

If I try to pass `pks` directly into `db.Update`, I get an error saying can't convert `[]uint64` to `[]interface`, so I had to convert each value individually. I'm also not a fan of the way I'm building the SQL string so that we're generating the list of `?` params for the IN clause.

Are there cleaner ways of performing these things?

Comment: You said you're getting those IDs from the DB in the first place, so I would suggest to use a subselect or join if possible to avoid passing those IDs in as query parameters at all.

Comment: The pk is part of a bigger select of other data, `SELECT pk, source, data, date_created, date_updated FROM events WHERE status = "NEW"` or something like that. During the process of scanning those values int and assigning them into a struct/model, I'm also saving the PK. I wanted to keep the type intact, as I didn't want to have issues with type incompatibility later on. @Adrian

Comment: You could use a query builder like [goqu](https://github.com/doug-martin/goqu) to cleanly build out queries that are normally clunky with just string formatting.